# Select unique MemberID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table [VotingStatusHistory]

with columns

```
[MemberID] | [AffilliationDate]
```

Same `MemberID` can have multiple `AffilliationDates`

```
31009 - 2011-04-28    
31009 - 2010-04-28    
31009 - 2009-04-28    
31009 - 2008-04-28    
31009 - 2007-04-28    
31009 - 2006-04-28
```

Now I would like to select MemberID's who only have a 2006 AffilliationDates record nothing else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So only member Ids with one affiliation date and the year of that date must be 2006?  `having min(year) = 2006 and max(year)=2006`? or by nothing else did you simply mean you only want to see the memberID column in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`...

```
SELECT  *
FROM    VotingStatusHistory 
WHERE   DATEPART(year,AffiliationDates) = 2006
AND MemberID NOT IN (SELECT MemeberID FROM VotingStatusHistory WHERE DATEPART(year,AffiliationDates) <> 2006)
```

Comment: No problem @raincheck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    VotingStatusHistory T1
WHERE   YEAR(T1.AffiliationDates) = 2006
    AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT      NULL
                        FROM        VotingStatusHistory T2
                        WHERE       YEAR(T2.AffiliationDates) <> 2006
                                AND T1.MemberID = T2.MemberID
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the except set operator. Why does no one learn these?

```
select vs.MemberID from dbo.VoterStatusHistory as vs 
where vs.AffiliationDate >= '20060101' and vs.AffiliationDate < '20070101'
except 
select vs.MemberID from dbo.VoterStatusHistory as vs 
where vs.AffiliationDate < '20060101' or vs.AffiliationDate >= '20070101'
```

Answer (score -1):

are you looking this?

```
Select * from yourtable where year(AffiliationDates) = 2006
```

Comment: Does not filter out the "nothing else" requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
select MemberID,
from VotingStatusHistory
group by MemberID
having sum(case when year(AffilliationDate)=2006 then 0 else 1 end)=0
```